# Data Frame: repacing inccorect values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I'm trying to replace the ingers for both 'score1' and 'score2'. Sometimes they print random numbers.

Strings replace correctly, but not integers.

```
import pandas as pd 

raw_data = {
    "city" : ["new york", "Sydney", "miami", "Rome", ],
    "rank": ["1st", "2nd", "2", "3"],
    "score1": [33, 48, 25, 33],
    "score2": [33, 48,33, 48]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,
                  index = pd.Index (['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], name = 'letter'),
                  columns = pd.Index(['city', 'rank', 'score1',  'score2'], name='attributes'))  

df['score1'].replace([33, 48, 25, 33], [1,2,3,4], inplace=True)
df['score2'].replace([33, 48,33, 48], [1,3,4,5], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: What is incorrect here? You are probably overwriting because you have 33 two times in the list.

Comment: correct. why cant you have two of the same numbers in a list?

Comment: What kind of behaviour do you expect in that case? Some of the 33s to be replaced with 1, the others with 4?